# Resolution method (of first-order predicate logic) to show that the following formulas are unsatisfiable

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic, satisfiability

below is the problem I have and I able to get the clauses from the given formula.

Below are my steps.

## EDIT

Formula
[image]

## EDIT

¬((∀y.q(y))∨¬(∀x.(q(x)∨r(x))∧(∃z.¬p(z)∧(p(z)∨¬r(x)))))

(∃y.¬q(y))∧¬¬(∀x.(q(x)∨r(x))∧(∃z.¬p(z)∧(p(z)∨¬r(x))))

∃y(¬q(y)∧(∀x.(q(x)∨r(x))∧(∃z.¬p(z)∧(p(z)∨¬r(x)))))

∃y∀x(¬q(y)∧((q(x)∨r(x))∧(∃z.¬p(z)∧(p(z)∨¬r(x)))))

∃y∀x∃z(¬q(y)∧((q(x)∨r(x))∧(¬p(z)∧(p(z)∨¬r(x)))))

standarize variables

∀x∃z(¬q(c)∧((q(x)∨r(x))∧(¬p(z)∧(p(z)∨¬r(x)))))

∀x(¬q(c)∧((q(x)∨r(x))∧(¬p(f(x))∧(p(f(x))∨¬r(x)))))

So i got below cluases

1. {¬q(c)}
2. {q(x),r(x)}
3. {¬p(f(x)}
4. {p(f(x),¬r(x)}
5. {¬r(x)} 3,4
6. {q(x)} 2,5

So I am in 5th step and I can't proceed further. is there any way that I can say c and x and equal and prove the given formula is unsatisfiable? I am confused. Can someone clear my doubt?

Comment: You seem to be missing some parentheses, otherwise you have some free (unquantified) variables) So, is your ¬((∀y.q(y))∨¬(∀x.(q(x)∨r(x))∧(∃z.¬p(z)∧(p(z)∨¬r(x))))) really ¬((∀y.q(y))∨¬(∀x.(q(x)∨r(x)∧ ∃z.(¬p(z)∧(p(z)∨¬r(x)))))?

Comment: @Bram28 I double checked the formula and added the given question as an image for your reference

Comment: Oh, I see, it uses a somewhat unusual notation of writing $(\forall x. ... )$ instead of the more common $\forall x (...)$.  OK, it's all good then, and I checked your work until the clauses, and that was all good too!

Comment: @Bram28 Thank you so much Bram. You always solve my confusions. I am really thankful :-)

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what you need to do: you 'unify' $q(x)$ and $\neg q(c)$ by substituting $c$ for $x$, and thus you get the empty clause.

You can do this because any variables that end up in the clauses come from universals, and so you can fill in any term for those variables you want, as long as you use that substitution systematically. That is you can 'unify' $q(x)$ and $\neg q(c)$, and also $q(x)$ and $\neg q(y)$, but not $f(x,x)$ and $f(a,b)$.

This process is called *unification* and is an important part of Resolution ... I am surprised you didn't run into that yet.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Actually, I am self-studying this logic subject since it is a prerequisite for my course. I will go through the unification theory again.

Comment: @user2397555 Ah, ok, good luck!  And you're doing good work!

Comment: Thank you so much. I learnt a lot from your explanations to my previous questions as well :-)

Comment: @user2397555 Cool! Always nice to be appreciated! :)